# Is there a possibility that I won't be able to print? (C, process)

Tags: c, process

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

int main() {

    pid_t c[2];
    int p[2];

    pipe(p);
    c[0] = fork();

    if (c[0] < 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "fork error");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    } else if (c[0] == 0) {
        // First child

        close(p[1]); // unuse
        close(STDIN_FILENO);
        dup(p[0]);

        char buf[BUFSIZ];
        read(STDIN_FILENO, buf, BUFSIZ);
        printf("Second child's print: %s\n", buf); // First Child's print
    } else {
        c[1] = fork();

        if (c[1] < 0) {
            fprintf(stderr, "fork error");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        else if (c[1] == 0) {
            // Second child

            close(p[0]); // unuse
            close(STDOUT_FILENO);
            dup(p[1]);
            printf("HI"); // Second child's print
        }
        else if (waitpid(c[0], NULL, 0) == -1 || waitpid(c[1], NULL, 0) == -1) {
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I wrote a code that the first child gets the message of second child's write() function through read() function from the first child.

if the first child is reaped before printing "HI", Is there a possibility that I won't be able to print?

if there is the possibility, How to solve it?

Comment: Re “if the first child is reaped before printing "HI"”: What are you asking? The first child is the one that prints “HI”. Reaping is releasing the resources of a terminated process. A process is not reaped until it is terminated, and the first child does not terminate until after it prints the message, unless something else causes it to terminate early. Nothing in your code sends a signal that would terminate it. What event are you concerned about? Did you ask about the right child? Or do you think the parent exiting might terminate the first child?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. When the first child calls `read()`, it will block waiting for something to be written to the pipe. It won't exit until the second child writes to the pipe, so the write won't fail.

The scenario you envision *could* occur if you put the pipe into non-blocking mode. Then `read()` won't wait for something to be written, and the first child could exit before the second child tries to write. If this happens, the second child will get a `SIGPIPE` signal when it calls `write()`.